# Toner light on a Brother 2170W

Tags: hardware-failure, laser-printer, toner

I've got a Brother 2170W with the toner light on, supposedly meaning the toner is empty. It's not.

It doesn't mind that I put in there a new unused toner, an empty toner or a refilled, the light doesn't go away.

I've tried resetling the gears, resetting the printer with the 2+5 presses of the Go button, the 2+7 presses (and when it prints, it says it has been correctly resetted), covering the holes with duct tape, and so on.

Anybody with more luck than I with this printer?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the printer's admin page?  I'm not sure there's anything you can **do** from there, but it might give you some more info about what it thinks the error is.

Comment: You mean it has a web admin page? Or the three paper pages Brother printers spit when you press the Go button three times? If you're talking about the paper pages, everything is ok.

Comment: I mean the web admin page.  Does it say anything more than "toner low"?  Can you use any of the admin reset tools to remove the warning?

Comment: If the toner light is on solid, it can also mean a Cartridge Position Error. Take the drum unit (not the cartridge) out of the printer and put it back in.